# View is not getting anything from the controller

Tags: laravel

Can anyone tell me why this will not return show.blade.php data?

ROUTE

```
Route::resource('news', 'NewsController', ['except' => ['create', 'store', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy']]);
```

MODEL

```
   public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ContentCategory::class);
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ContentTag::class);
    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
 public function show(News $news)
    {   
        $news->load('categories', 'tags', 'product_press_releases', 'section');

        return view('site.news.show', compact('news'));
    }
```

VIEW show.blade.php

```
@section('content')
{{ $news->title  ?? '' }}
{{ $news->id  ?? '' }}

@foreach($news->categories as $key => $category)
 <span class="label label-info">{{ $category->name }}</span>
@endforeach

@endcontent
```

For the life of me I cannot get why no data is being returned. I do these all the time and never ran into this.

Comment: Try `dd($news)` before the `return` statement

Comment: I did the data is loaded I mean there are data in the $news

Comment: Can you try `dd($news)` in your blade and let me know if there are any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your are not extending it to `app.blade.php`.

Add - `@extends('YOUR_APP_LINK')`.

In your case -

```
@extends('YOUR_APP_LINK')
@section('content')
{{ $news->title  ?? '' }}
{{ $news->id  ?? '' }}

@foreach($news->categories as $key => $category)
 <span class="label label-info">{{ $category->name }}</span>
@endforeach

@endcontent
```

Hope this will help you.